# GHS label layout

Tags: labels, chemistry, sticky-labels

I have a rough draft of some GHS labels
using the `labels` and `ghsystem` packages::

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{ghsystem}

\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\LabelCols=2
\LabelRows=5

\LabelGridtrue % show grid for labels

% Signal words.
\newcommand{\warning}{{\color{red}{\textbf{WARNING}}}}
\newcommand{\danger}{{\color{red}{\textbf{DANGER}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{labels}
  \textbf{Calcium chloride}
  \warning
  \ghs*{h}{319}
  \ghs*[dots=skin]{p}{264} \ghs*{p}{280}
  \ghs*{p}{305+351+338} \ghs*{p}{337+313}
  \ghspic{exclam}

  \textbf{1-Methyl-2-pyrrolidine}
  \danger
  \ghs*{h}{227} \ghs*{h}{315} \ghs*{h}{319} \ghs*{h}{335} \ghs*{h}{360}
  % Precautions do not fit.
  %\ghs*{p}{201} \ghs*{p}{202} \ghs*{p}{210} \ghs*{p}{261} \ghs*[dots=skin]{p}{264} \ghs*{p}{271} \ghs*{p}{280} \ghs*{p}{302+352} \ghs*{p}{304+340+312} \ghs*{p}{305+351+338} \ghs*{p}{308+313} \ghs*{p}{332+313} \ghs*{p}{337+313} \ghs*{p}{362} \ghs*[dots=dry sand or dry chemical or alcohol-resistant foam]{p}{370+378} \ghs*{p}{403+233} \ghs*{p}{403+235} \ghs*{p}{405} \ghs*[dots=an approved waste disposal plant]{p}{501}
  \ghspic{health}\ghspic{exclam}

  \textbf{Methanol}
  \danger
  \ghs*{h}{225} \ghs*{h}{301} \ghs*{h}{311} \ghs*{h}{331} \ghs*{h}{370}
  % Precautions do not fit.
  %\ghs*{p}{210} \ghs*{p}{233} \ghs*{p}{240} \ghs*{p}{241} \ghs*{p}{242} \ghs*{p}{243} \ghs*{p}{260} \ghs*[dots=skin]{p}{264} \ghs*{p}{270} \ghs*{p}{271} \ghs*{p}{280} \ghs*{p}{301} \ghs*{p}{310} \ghs*{p}{330} \ghs*{p}{303+361+353} \ghs*{p}{304+340+311} \ghs*{p}{307+311} \ghs*{p}{362} \ghs*[dots=dry sand or dry chemical or alcohol-resistant foam]{p}{370+378} \ghs*{p}{403+233} \ghs*{p}{403+235} \ghs*{p}{405} \ghs*[dots=an approved waste disposal plant]{p}{501}
  \ghspic{flame}\ghspic{skull}\ghspic{health}

  \textbf{Ammonia}
  \danger
  \ghs*{h}{221} \ghs*{h}{280} \ghs*{h}{314} \ghs*{h}{331} \ghs*{h}{410}
  % Precautions do not fit.
  % \ghs*{p}{210} \ghs*{p}{261} \ghs*[dots=skin]{p}{264} \ghs*{p}{271} \ghs*{p}{273} \ghs*{p}{280} \ghs*{p}{301+330+331} \ghs*{p}{303+361+353} \ghs*{p}{304+340+310} \ghs*{p}{305+338+310} \ghs*{p}{363} \ghs*{p}{377} \ghs*{p}{381} \ghs*{p}{391} \ghs*{p}{403+233} \ghs*{p}{405} \ghs*{p}{410+403} \ghs*[dots=an approved waste disposal plant]{p}{501}
  \ghspic{bottle}\ghspic{skull}\ghspic{acid}\ghspic{aqpol}
\end{labels}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image: original label layout]

However, there are some issues I would like to resolve:

- There isn't enough room for all the precautionary statements.

Making the font smaller helps a little, but not enough.

- The hazard communication pictograms would be better placed in the upper right.

This way there is more room for the hazard and precautionary statements.

- The font size for product identifiers should be larger.

Some chemical names are quite long, so it's hard to choose a consistent size.
It should be larger than the rest of the text,
but small enough to leave room for the hazard and precautionary statements.

Here's a mockup I made in GIMP:

[image: better label layout]

It puts the product identifier (e.g. "Methanol"),
pictograms, and signal words (e.g. "DANGER") together in a box,
leaving the rest of the space for hazard and precautionary statements.

How can I achieve this layout (or similar) with LaTeX?

Comment: Have you tried using `minipage`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nice solution using `stackengine` and `adjustbox`. Effectively it creates a short stack and shifts it up, so that it fits image positioning. Feel free to experiment with the `raise` values.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ghsystem}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\LabelCols=2
\LabelRows=5

\LabelGridtrue % show grid for labels

% Signal words.
\newcommand{\warning}{{\color{red}{\textbf{WARNING}}}}
\newcommand{\danger}{{\color{red}{\textbf{DANGER}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{labels}
  \adjustbox{raise=1.5em}{\mbox{\stackengine{\stackgap}{\textbf{\Large Calcium chloride}}{\warning}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}}}\hfill\ghspic{exclam}\\
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\ghs*{h}{319}\ghs*[dots=skin]{p}{264} \ghs*{p}{280}\ghs*{p}{305+351+338} \ghs*{p}{337+313}}

  \adjustbox{raise=1.5em}{\mbox{\stackengine{\stackgap}{\textbf{\Large 1-Methyl-2-pyrrolidine}}{\danger}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}}}\hfill\ghspic{health}\ghspic{exclam}\\
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\ghs*{h}{225} \ghs*{h}{315} \ghs*{h}{319} \ghs*{h}{335} \ghs*{h}{360}}

  \adjustbox{raise=1.5em}{\mbox{\stackengine{\stackgap}{\textbf{\Large Methanol}}{\danger}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}}}\hfill\ghspic{flame}\ghspic{skull}\ghspic{health}\\
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\ghs*{h}{225} \ghs*{h}{301} \ghs*{h}{311} \ghs*{h}{331} \ghs*{h}{370}}

  \adjustbox{raise=1.5em}{\mbox{\stackengine{\stackgap}{\textbf{\Large Ammonia}}{\danger}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}}}\hfill\ghspic{bottle}\ghspic{skull}\ghspic{acid}\ghspic{aqpol}\\
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\ghs*{h}{221} \ghs*{h}{280} \ghs*{h}{314} \ghs*{h}{331} \ghs*{h}{410}}
\end{labels}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some chemical names are very long (e.g. "ammonium molybdate tetrahydrate"). Would it be possible to wrap those onto more than one line?

Comment: @bariumbitmap A quick fix for manual breaking: `\adjustbox{raise=2.5em}{\mbox{\stackengine{\stackgap}{\stackengine{\stackgap}{\textbf{\Large Ammonium Molybdate}}{\textbf{\Large Tetrahydrate}}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}}{\warning}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}}}\hfill\ghspic{exclam}\\ ` (you can stack as many as you want), but I'll try to make it auomated (therefore no edit yet).

Comment: That's alright; I shouldn't have piled on requirements that go beyond the original question. The existing answer is sufficient for now.